# yum and dnf install/update takes 5 minutes to start on RHEL8

Tags: ansible, yum, rhel, dnf

If I run yum or dnf as root on most recent updated RHEL8 it works smoothly. As soon as I try running it with sudo users (added to wheel group) it takes up to 5 minutes.

Doing a yum clean did not help eiher.

I usually run updates using Ansible from a remote host but Ansible disconnects after several minutes of trying to run the yum module.

I set SELinux to disabled, just in case and checked proxy settings in dnf.conf - It all looks fine. Any input is very much appreciated.

This is the dnf.log

```
2020-02-20T15:33:13Z INFO Updating Subscription Management repositories.
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DEBUG DNF version: 4.2.7
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DDEBUG Command: yum update
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DDEBUG Installroot: /
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DDEBUG Releasever: 8
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DEBUG cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DDEBUG Base command: update
2020-02-20T15:37:36Z DDEBUG Extra commands: ['update']
2020-02-20T15:37:37Z DEBUG repo: using cache for: epel-modular
2020-02-20T15:37:37Z DEBUG epel-modular: using metadata from Sat Feb 15 03:19:39 2020.
2020-02-20T15:37:37Z DEBUG repo: using cache for: epel
2020-02-20T15:37:37Z DEBUG epel: using metadata from Thu Feb 20 06:38:22 2020.
2020-02-20T15:37:38Z DEBUG reviving: 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms' can be revived - repomd matches.
2020-02-20T15:37:38Z DEBUG rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms: using metadata from Thu Feb 13 10:30:57 2020.
2020-02-20T15:37:38Z DEBUG reviving: 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms' can be revived - repomd matches.
2020-02-20T15:37:39Z DEBUG rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms: using metadata from Thu Feb 20 11:06:31 2020.
2020-02-20T15:37:39Z DDEBUG timer: sack setup: 3550 ms
2020-02-20T15:37:39Z DEBUG Completion plugin: Generating completion cache...
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z DEBUG --> Starting dependency resolution
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z DEBUG --> Finished dependency resolution
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z DDEBUG timer: depsolve: 277 ms
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z INFO Dependencies resolved.
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z INFO Nothing to do.
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z INFO Complete!
2020-02-20T15:37:40Z DDEBUG Cleaning up.
```

Comment: Welcome to SatckOverflow! StackOverflow is designed to accumulate questions and answers related to software development. Your have more chances for the answer at  https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The proxy was not correctly set in /etc/rhsm/rhsm.conf
I don't understand why running as root would not cause the same problem.